# Rails Server vs. Console: What's the difference?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, swig

Hello people who know more than me.

I am calling a c++-library through a swig wrapper. When I run it in the rails console, and when I call it through my specs, it works fine. However, when I call it when in server mode, it gives

> SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
>   actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:79:in `'

And that's it!

Does the fact that the problem occurs in server mode only point to anything in particular? No idea how to debug this.

I've been using this in server mode for some time. But I restructured things slightly (called different methods within the c++ API) and it all broke suddenly, and only in server mode.

An example (not sure it's terribly illuminating):

```
require 'awcbc' # Not gemified - is this significant? The awcbc.bundle et al is just plonked in an app/cbc directory

class SolverOfThings < ActiveRecord::Base

    def solve_something
        model = Awcbc::Model_Builder.new
        model.solve # Calls C++ library.
    end

end
```

Calling SolverOfThings::solve_something from, say, a controller, via html, breaks. Going into rails c and calling it, doesn't.

I tried increasing the ruby stack size to something ridiculous, but no dice.

Sorry, that's all I've got. Any clues?

Comment: The line of the stack trace you show is just the cleanup/reraise in Reloader, can you add the whole stack trace to your question please.

Comment: ha - when you have a stack-overflow... increasing the size of the stack won't help... you have something that is calling itself infinite numbers of times... unless you can create a literally infinite stack, you will continue to get StackOverflow (and even if you could accomplish such a feat, it wouldn't make the code work) ;)

Comment: Sorry @smathy, that is the entire stack trace. Would love to add more. It crashes badly. Or is there a way to request more?

Comment: Hah - thanks Taryn. Stacks are finite size, it is possible to overflow it without an infinite loop. As the error occurs in console but not server, this was not a silly thing to try. Perhaps that c-library was almost filling my ruby stack, and the added overhead / recursion of the server was overflowing it. It's not this, though, you are right that it's almost certainly an infinite loop.

Comment: @TonyWright not sure if you can request more if it doesn't show any more than that. Sorry, no clue on your issue, too many moving parts for me.